# VS2010 Looking for file in wrong directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio is looking in a completely wrong directory for a CS file.

```
 C:\TRUNK\MAIN\APPRESOURCES\APPINFO.CS
```

I can't even find the Trunk file at this location.

Correct Path:

```
 C:\Code\Branches\BR5\MAIN\APPRESOURCES\APPINFO.CS
```

I've tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, excluding and adding the file back to my solution.

Call Stack Loaction:

```
FormsDevShared.dll!FormsDevShared.AppInfo.Instance()
```

Heres the Stack Trace:

Locating source for 'C:\TRUNK\MAIN\APPRESOURCES\APPINFO.CS'.
Checksum: MD5 {ed 8a ff 89 84 3d 16 7e 9f 76 af 57 18 9f 62 7a}
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: C:\Code\Branches\BR5\MAIN\APPRESOURCES\APPINFO.CS
Checksum: MD5 {c5 33 96 ef ab 76 b1 3b aa 55 70 76 1b b5 d4 cf} Checksum doesn't match.
The file 'C:\TRUNK\MAIN\APPRESOURCES\APPINFO.CS' does not exist.

Line of Code Throwing exception:

```
  FormsDevShared.AppInfo.Instance().User = AppInfo.Instance().DBContext.User;
```

FormsDevShared is the namespace containing AppInfo.

Comment: If you open your csproj file in a text editor and search for appinfo.cs, in what folder is it registered there?

Comment: I found a bad output path in the .csproj but that did not solve the problem check update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably that the reference to the file in the project file uses an absolute address instead of a relative address.

In the VS project explorer, first exculde the Appinfo.cs that is pointing to the wrong location, then add existing file and include the file from the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a solution that I had branched from in Team Foundation Server. The solution file in the branch pointed to the project folder for the other branch. I could not get it to switch so I did what @Ryan O'Neill suggested and opened the .sln file in notepad and replaced all of the bad folder names with the correct ones. I had to remove the Read Only property on the solution file to save it; but after saving it, my solution then pointed to the correct project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open the .csproj(or .vbproj) in a text editor.  Search for the bad path and replace it with the correct one.